# Invoke Search Template URI using RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

We are trying to query from ElasticSearchDB the pseudo code is as shown below.

```
public String searchMovieRelease(){ 
    String movieRelease=null;
    WebTarget   webTarget = target.path("_search/template");     (1)
    Invocation.Builder builder = getInvokationBuilder(target);       (2)
    movieRelease = builder.post(Entity.json(query));                 (3)
    return movieRelease;
}
```

1. Fetch the target which points to the required URI.
2. Fetch the build
3. Post the request the query through the builder and obtain the response from elastic search.

Now, how do, I achieve the same using RestHighLevelClient.

Comment: note, if you using Elasticsearch > 7.15 you should use their java-api client as JHLRC is deprecated from 7.15

Comment: @Amit I am  using 7.4 version of ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
var client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create("host"))
            .setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(60000).setSocketTimeout(60000)));
var lowClient = client.getLowLevelClient();
var request = new Request("GET", "endpoint");
var response = lowClient.performRequest(request);
```